# How to get value of current item using jquery inside loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have tried the following code in a template file of wordpress.

```
  <?php query_posts('showposts=9&post_type=packages&packages_category='.$category.'&order=ASC&paged='.$paged); ?>          <?php while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
     ...
     ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".package-book a").click(function(){
         var $temp = '<?php the_title(); ?>';
             $('.book-title').val(' '); 
                $('.book-title').val($temp);     
         });
        });
      </script> 
             <span class="package-book"> 
            <a href="...">Book</a>
            </span>
           <?php endwhile; ?>
```

and there's is input type text with class book-title
as `<input type="text" class="book-title"/>`
When anchor tag with class package-book is clicked it should display
current value of  `<?php the_title(); ?>` in the textbox
but the above jquery code displays value of last item in the loop in all the 
input text box. I want it should display the value of current title 
in the input type textbox. 
Please help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend adding JS to a PHP Loop. Instead assign the values as data-attributes. For example when you build out this span give it a data-title of the post title:

**PHP**

```
<span class="package-book"> 
    <a href="..." data-title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>">Book</a>
</span>
```

**jQuery** (outside of php loop)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".package-book a").on('click', function(){
        $('.book-title').val($(this).data('title'));
    });
});
```